# strip out div and CDATA in Sharepoint Online list XML

Tags: sharepoint-online, xml

I have used PowerShell to export the SharePoint list to the XMl. The data from the list are tagged inside "`<description><![CDATA[<div><b>`"; Is this normal ? Is there anyway to strip out  and any other  or  ?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--RSS generated by Microsoft SharePoint Foundation RSS Generator on 8/13/2017 7:15:27 AM -->
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/sites/myschool/_layouts/15/RssXslt.aspx?List=6a8abf96-2af1-4279-aa97-189ca6ad4182" version="1.0"?>
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>Student Meetings</title>
    <link>https://myschool.sharepoint.com/sites/myschool/Lists/Student Meetings/AllItems.aspx</link>
    <description>RSS feed for the Student Meetings list.</description>
    <lastBuildDate>Sun, 13 Aug 2017 14:15:27 GMT</lastBuildDate>
    <generator>Microsoft SharePoint Foundation RSS Generator</generator>
    <ttl>60</ttl>
    <language>en-US</language>
    <image>
      <title>Student Meetings</title>
      <url>https://myschool.sharepoint.com/sites/myschool/_layouts/15/images/siteIcon.png</url>
      <link>https://myschool.sharepoint.com/sites/myschool/Lists/Student Meetings/AllItems.aspx</link>
    </image>

    <item>
      <title>Meeting 1</title>
      <link>https://myschool.sharepoint.com/sites/myschool/Lists/Student Meetings/DispForm.aspx?ID=25</link>
      <description><![CDATA[<div><b>Number of attendees:</b> 5</div>
<div><b>Location:</b> Room101</div>
<div><b>Start Time:</b> 11/08/2017 10:00</div>
<div><b>End Time:</b> 11/08/2017 13:00</div>
<div><b>Chair Person:</b> Joe Blogg</div>
<div><b>Notes:</b> notes goes here, notes goes here </div>
]]></description>
      <author>Jane Doe</author>
      <pubDate>Wed, 09 Aug 2017 11:02:57 GMT</pubDate>
      <guid isPermaLink="true">https://myschool.sharepoint.com/sites/myschool/Lists/Student Meetings/DispForm.aspx?ID=25</guid>
    </item>

        <item>
      <title>Meeting 2</title>
      <link>https://myschool.sharepoint.com/sites/myschool/Lists/Student Meetings/DispForm.aspx?ID=25</link>
      <description><![CDATA[<div><b>Number of attendees:</b> 5</div>
<div><b>Location:</b> Room101</div>
<div><b>Start Time:</b> 12/08/2017 15:00</div>
<div><b>End Time:</b> 12/08/2017 16:00</div>
<div><b>Chair Person:</b> Joe Blogg</div>
<div><b>Notes:</b> notes goes here, notes goes here </div>
]]></description>
      <author>Jane Doe</author>
      <pubDate>Wed, 09 Aug 2017 13:02:57 GMT</pubDate>
      <guid isPermaLink="true">https://myschool.sharepoint.com/sites/myschool/Lists/Student Meetings/DispForm.aspx?ID=25</guid>
    </item>

  </channel>
</rss>
```

Any help on this will be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're doing it this way rather than using one of the APIs? https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/choose-the-right-api-set-in-sharepoint - normally you'd use the CSOM with PowerShell to fetch list data

Comment: Hi Sasfrog, We have an inhouse PHP application that reads the data from the XML and displays on the digital signage.